# OpenCV Install problems windows

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I want to install OpenCV 2.4.6 On Code::blocks

I already  linked the files in the compiler settings

C:\OpenCV\cv\include
C:\OpenCV\cvaux\include
C:\OpenCV\cxcore\include
C:\OpenCV\otherlibs\highgui
C:\OpenCV\otherlibs\cvcam\include

and   Linker 
C:OpenCV\lib

but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you build opencv with the same compiler that you have in codeblocks? Or at least download precompiled libraries for the compiler that codeblocks is using? mingw?

Comment: there's no more cvaux or cxcore or cvcam. that part comes from another millenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no more cvaux or cxcore or cvcam. 
that part comes from another millenium

use: c:/opencv/build/include for the includes,

and the mingw folder for the linker ( there's an additional x64 / x86 hurdle built in, can't remember, but you'll manage! )